# Capturing WM_MOUSEMOVE events in parent window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouseevent

I have a (parent) window in which a child-window is created by a another library (Ogre3d). Window initialization uses the bare Win32 API.

I'd like to capture the mouse input in my parent window, but it seems like I my WM_MOUSEMOVE events are received only by the child-window, which makes sense, since that fills all of my client-area.

Is there a way to capture the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages in the parent window or (unintrusively) redirect those messages from the child-window?

Comment: Using Spy++ can you verify that your parent window ever gets mouse messages?  It seems like that it never would in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can obtain a handle to the window in question you can [subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183%28VS.85%29.aspx) it.

In a nutshell, you get to register a callback function that gets a crack at all of the messages sent to the sub-classed window.

The linked article should get you where you need to be.

Comment: I recommend intercepting `WM_NCHITTEST` and making it always return `HTTRANSPARENT`.  Then the parent will receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages and you do not need to translate the coordinates.